# Custom Makefile With Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project with 3 .hpp files and 1 .cpp file, and a custom Makefile. The code and the Makefile for this project already existed, so I right clicked in the Project Explorer, and did **Import->Existing Code as Makefile Project** I named my project and pointed the location to the root dir of the project which contains all of my files. And I selected MinGW GCC as my toolchain because that is the compiler that I have. Then I went to **Project->Properties->C/C++ Build** and unchecked **Generate Makefiles automatically**

Then I changed my **Build directory** by choosing **File system** and navigating to the root directory of my project which contains all of my files. The Build directory is **C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\School\CSE\CSE 100\pa1-rbridges**

Then I changed the **Build command** to **make -f C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\School\CSE\CSE 100\pa1-rbridges\Makefile bst** where **bst** is a target in my Makefile and my Makefile is at that location. When I click the hammer on the toolbar to build my project, nothing happens. When I try to run my project, I get **Launch failed: Binary not found.**

I just want my project to use my Makefile and build properly. 
I have searched Google and stack overflow for hours trying to figure out how to get this to work and have had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to these sorts of problems usually begins with breaking them down.

First try and build build from the command line.  Does the "make -f ..." work from the command line?

It could be an issue with MinGW not working properly.

It sounds like you have done everything correctly as far as eclipse goes.  You may find a clue in the eclipse console window.

Comment: The eclipse console window is completely blank when I try to build.
My original build command did not work from the command line, but when I add quotes it does work. Still no luck in eclipse though. The new build command is 

make -f "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\School\CSE\CSE 100\pa1-rbridges\Makefile" bst

Answer (score 0):

Too late for giving an answer. But this is for the other people who end up here.

You need to create a new run configuration in **Run->Run Configuration...** for your project, and then type a name for the output binary file like **Debug\name.exe** in 'C/C++ Application' box. The name must be the same as the project name.